# unbound method x() must be called with y instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python, multithreading, instance

My Python-program has quite a lot of code so I hope you're fine that I give you the part of the code my problem is about. I've created a thread for Tkinter and I am trying to access a function within this thread. This is what it looks like:

```
class GUI (threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self, num):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)

     def run(self):
         window = Tk()
         window.title('GUI')
         window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
         window.pack()


     def output(lampe, status):
         if status == 0:

             if lampe == 21:
                 window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
             if lampe == 20:
                 window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

 GUI.output(21,0)
```

And this is the message I get:

`TypeError: unbound method output() must be called with GUI instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`

To be honest, I do not know what the instance is that I have to refer as the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access it as a static method, so you'll need to annotate it with [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```
    @staticmethod
    def output(lampe, status):
         if status == 0:

             if lampe == 21:
                 window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
             if lampe == 20:
                 window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")
```

Comment: Thank you, that one worked. But now I get another error message: ' in output
    window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
NameError: global name 'window' is not defined '. Is there a way to get access to 'window' from the output-function?

Comment: @lumpi You could fix this by adding `global window` to the start of the `run` method, but you'll most likely get many more errors.

Comment: This was my first intention. To my surprise, I do not get any other errors - I see exactly the same one. Works neither in the `run`-method nor outside.

Comment: Did you call `run` at all?

Comment: @lumpi can u check with my code? I would like to improve my code if its not working

Comment: `window` is a local variable in the `run` method. It is neither global nor accessible via the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Instance is the object instance that python functions require, in your case 'self'
read this wonderful explanation in [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) . You need to understand why self is used in class methods in python. For Your problem look into this code.

```
class GUI (threading.Thread):
     window=object
     def __init__(self, num):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)

     def run(self):
         self.window = Tk()
         self.window.title('GUI')
         self.window = Canvas(self.window, width=400, height=200)
         self.window.pack()

     @staticmethod
     def output(lampe, status):
         if status == 0:

             if lampe == 21:
                 window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
             if lampe == 20:
                 window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

 GUI.output(21,0)
```

other implementation for the OP

```
class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('GUI')
        self.window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
        self.window.pack()

    def output(self,lampe, status):
        if status == 0:
            if lampe == 21:
                self.window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
            if lampe == 20:
                self.window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")
```

and implement this

```
gui=Gui()
thread=threading.Thread(target=gui.output, args=(21,0))
thread.start()
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. You're still trying to access `output` from the class, without creating an instance. This code will now raise TypeError.

Comment: If you access `cls.window` it'll be `object`. If you'd like to have `cls` as a parameter, you'd have to annotate it with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Comment: No, now you're confused between staticmethod and classmethod. The latter takes `cls` as the first parameter, but staticmethod doesn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well but then unless he initializes a window he wont be able to call the functions right? He will get global name window not defined.?

Comment: Okay, this has been fixed a couple of times yet. With the latest one I still have the issue that window is not global. So I have added the line `window global`. Now this is what I get: `AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'create_oval'`

Comment: @lumpi i would like to know what exactly is your purpose and what do you want as the final output??

Comment: window.create_oval should create a circle in the TkInter-window that is called 'window'. This has worked so far that way before I tried to put all of this into the `GUI`-class. Worked fine on Windows, but the Linux-version (Raspberry Pi in my case) was not working because I had only the mainloop()-part in the thread.

Comment: @lumpi and do you need to do it with a thread?? really?? or just a circle is fine?

Comment: Yup, it's necessary because otherwise the program stops if it's not made in a thread. For Python on a Windows-machine it was okay to simply put mainloop() into a single thread and the program was running fine. But that does not work on other platforms, see [this one](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.python/-runtimeerror-calling-tcl-from-different-app/1636001).

Comment: @lumpi chek the new implementation i have done for you. and respond if it works

Comment: I think `gui=GUI()` (upper case) was meant instead? I've tried this, the result is `...line 267, in <module>
    gui=GUI()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` It seems to access the wrong method.

Comment: Since the initial problem has been fixed for a while now, I hope you understand that I opened another topic for the method-calling issues I have now. You can find the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388796).
I am very thankful for all of your support so far.