# Python function calls the wrong method/target

Tags: python, multithreading, init

The following program simulates a traffic light system with some buttons. The buttons appear correctly, but if I'm trying to call the method to create/change the LEDs, it ends up in the wrong method. Here's the important part of the code:

```
class GUI (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global window
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Ampel GUI')
        window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
        window.pack()

        button1 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(25))
        button1.pack()
        button1.place(x=190, y=70)

        button2 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(12))
        button2.pack()
        button2.place(x=115, y=160)

        (...)

        button6 = Button(window, text="V2", command=lambda: pushbutton(22)) # V2
        button6.pack()
        button6.place(x=280, y=130)
        window.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def output(self, lampe, status):
        if status == 0:
            if lampe == 21:
                window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
            if lampe == 20:
                window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

callthread=GUI()
callthread=threading.Thread(target=GUI.output, args=(21,0))
callthread.start()
```

How do I fix the callthread-part, so that the output method is called with the arguments (21,0)? Right now all that it ends up with is
`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

//edit: This is how the fixed version looks like:
    class GUI (threading.Thread):

```
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global window
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Ampel GUI')
        window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
        window.pack()

        button1 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(25))
        button1.pack()
        button1.place(x=190, y=70)

        button2 = Button(window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(12))
        button2.pack()
        button2.place(x=115, y=160)

        (...)

        button6 = Button(window, text="V2", command=lambda: pushbutton(22)) # V2
        button6.pack()
        button6.place(x=280, y=130)
        window.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def output(lampe, status):
        if status == 0:
            if lampe == 21:
                window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
            if lampe == 20:
                window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

callthread=GUI()
callthread=threading.Thread(target=GUI.output, args=(21,0))
callthread.start()
```

Comment: the problem is here: `callthread=GUI()`

Comment: You changed your `__init__` method in your last edit.  You should no longer get the `TypeError` with the latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is on this line:

```
callthread=GUI()
```

The problem is that `__init__` was defined as:

```
def __init__(self, num):
```

So either provide an argument when creating a `GUI` object, or remove the `num` argument from the `__init__` method.

**note:**  This answer applies to the code prior to your edit.  After your edit you removed the `num` argument from `__init__`.  You should no longer get the `TypeError` with your edited code.

Comment: Sorry about that. To avoid any misunderstanding for later visitors, I've posted both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `num` argument from `__init__()` and the `self` argument from `output()` since it is a static method.

Comment: Done this, thank you. Now this is message I get: line 117, in output window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6") NameError: global name 'window' is not defined. Even though it gets defined as window = Tk().
I am trying to fix this by myself. I will comment the result here soon.

Comment: either add `global window` to `output()` or move the `window = Tk()` line so it is before the `class GUI (...):` line...

Comment: Moving `window = Tk` before the `class GUI` ended in a lot of errors (referenced before assignment, etc.), adding it to the `output`-method did not changed anything. Do you see any way to get the `window.create_oval`-part working so that it creates the ovals in the run-method?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should not make  a static method and no need to make it global.

> Remember dont try to subclass threading.Thread if are not clear about how it works. Instead use the following approach. It will do everything easy for you without sub classing thread.

**try this:**

```
class  GUI()
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Ampel GUI')
        self.window = Canvas(window, width=400, height=200)
        self.window.pack()

        button1 = Button(self.window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(25))
        button1.pack()
        button1.place(x=190, y=70)

        button2 = Button(self.window, text="Press", command=lambda: pushbutton(12))
        button2.pack()
        button2.place(x=115, y=160)

        (...)

        button6 = Button(self.window, text="V2", command=lambda: pushbutton(22)) # V2
        button6.pack()
        button6.place(x=280, y=130)
        window.mainloop()

    def output(lampe, status):
        if status == 0:
            if lampe == 21:
                self.window.create_oval(140, 30, 160, 10, fill="#FFA6A6")
            if lampe == 20:
                self.window.create_oval(170, 30, 190, 10, fill="#FAFAAA")

callthread=GUI()
callthread=threading.Thread(target=callthread.output, args=(21,0))
callthread.start()
```